# How can I install MS OneNote offline?

Tags: microsoft-onenote, installer

is there a Microsoft Onenote which is free, standalone offline installer for windows?
onenote.com offers a installer but i want a version to install on an offline PC.

Comment: How is this off-topic? It's a question about a **computer software** program. It is a question on **where to find a specific installer** for a **specific** program, not a request for a recommendation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In [this forum](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/office/forum/office_2013_release-onenote/possible-to-download-standalone-copy-of-onenote/2456b5e0-1f8b-4e0a-b504-d05004592781) I've found a link to [OneNote item in e-shop](http://www.microsoftstore.com/store/msca/en_CA/pdp/OneNote-2013-Non-Commercial/productID.260245500) which should give you a standalone installer (they say). As you can see from other posts, standalone installers are not normally available.

I think the reason is logical: **[free version](http://onenote.com)** of OneNote stores all notebooks exclusively on OneDrive so the PC must be online not only during installation, but also when OneNote is used.

**[Paid non-commercial version](http://www.microsoftstore.com/store/msca/en_CA/pdp/OneNote-2013-Non-Commercial/productID.260245500)** which is relatively cheap, should be able to record audio/video and work standalone, *without the OneDrive storage*. So if you say your PC is offline, you might still need commercial version which has ability to store notebooks locally in your PC.

Comment: Actually that is not true. The free version also can store notebooks on the local harddisk.

Comment: @Picl – thank you for feedback. Free version can store notebooks on local harddisk as part of OneDrive folder. Could you post any references showing something else? But the [question](https://superuser.com/q/869331/287473) is about standalone installer of OneNote and not about storage location of OneNote files so in this Q/A we should primarily focus on this.

Comment: sorry for the (very) late answer, but I use the free version offline all the time. So there doesn't seem to be any problem with that.